# redirect parent page using an anchor text

Tags: javascript, redirect, iframe

Can I redirect the parent page through an anchor text from Javascript within an iFrame?

Comment: Come with word you have understand and what you have tried and what you want!

Comment: Please edit your question so it is a complete question that does not depend on an external resources to be understood.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `parent.location=url;` in Javascript

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.